# Is there a way to set the framerate or individual frame pitches in JythonMusic?

Tags: audio, jython, wav, jython-music

I am trying to create a program in JythonMusic, that changes the pitch from one wav-file into the pitch from another wav-file.

The idea I have is:

->Open wav-file that sets the pitch and length (framerate)

->While wav-file.length not empty:

Save wav.frame.pitch & wav.frame somewhere

->Open second wav-file whose pitch and length have to get modified to fit wav1

->While wav.frame not empty:

Apply wav.frame.pitch to second-wav.frame

...

Anyways that's the basic idea, now I don't seem to find any way to set the framerate or apply the pitch to a single frame on a wav-file.

I can however change the pitch for the entire wav-file... but that's not really what I want.

(**Just to clarify this, but this is a JythonMusic-question. Not a Jython-question...**)

Answer (score 0):

JythonMusic allows getting and setting the pitch (or frequency) of entire wav files  - see [AudioSample](https://jythonmusic.me/api/audiosample/) *getPitch()* and *setPitch()* functions.

This is probably what you want.

A wav frame is too low of a level to think about pitch or frequency, as it just stores a number, the amplitude (or loudness) of sound at this particular instance in time.